# auto inserção de timestamp MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou usando a opção ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, mas o formato que é atualizado na tabela vem neste formato: `"2017-06-07 13:05:02"`, eu gostaria que fosse em segundos assim: `1496851485`, o mais curioso é que quando eu faço a comparação destes tipos de timestamp num statment a condição é dada como verdadeira, por exemplo:

```
"SELECT author, comment, timestamp FROM comments WHERE timestamp > :requestedTimestamp"
```

sendo o timestamp do banco no formato `"2017-06-07 13:05:02"` e o :requestedTimestamp `1496851485`, O MySQL faz a conversão automática ou isso é um bug? porque mesmo eu colocando uma data bem antiga ele ainda funciona...

Answer (score 0):

O MySQL vai armazenar tipos datetime/timestamp internamente em formato binário. O formato que é exibido para você não necessariamente reflete o formato interno.

Para trabalhar com os tipos datetime/timestamp em segundos use a função `TO_SECONDS()`.

Uma query que compara um datetime/timestamp com um valor inteiro vai funcionar porque o MySQL faz conversão de tipos automaticamente, conforme explica a documentação https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html.

Veja este exemplo:

```
mysql> USE test1;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ->     added_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    ->     updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (added_id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT SLEEP(5);
+----------+
| SLEEP(5) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (5.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT added_id, updated_at, TO_SECONDS(updated_at), updated_at+0 FROM table1;
+----------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| added_id | updated_at          | TO_SECONDS(updated_at) | updated_at+0   |
+----------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|        1 | 2017-06-08 20:50:17 |            63664174217 | 20170608205017 |
|        2 | 2017-06-08 20:50:22 |            63664174222 | 20170608205022 |
+----------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note que a função `TO_SECONDS()` traz o valor em segundos desde o ano 0. 
Note também que ao fazer uma operação de soma da data com zero, o comando é aceito, mas verificamos que o valor inteiro armazenado não corresponde aos segundos.

As duas queries abaixo vão funcionar:

```
mysql> SELECT added_id, updated_at FROM table1 WHERE updated_at > 20170608205017
;
+----------+---------------------+
| added_id | updated_at          |
+----------+---------------------+
|        2 | 2017-06-08 20:50:22 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE TO_SECONDS(updated_at) > 63664174217;
+----------+---------------------+
| added_id | updated_at          |
+----------+---------------------+
|        2 | 2017-06-08 20:50:22 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```